# undefined reference to `soup_session_new'

Tags: vala

I am trying to make a get request in vala following this: https://wiki.gnome.org/Vala/LibSoupSample. I do exactly what it says and the compiler throws this:

```
Connection.vala.c:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `soup_session_new'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: cc exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

And this is the result from `pkg-config --libs --cflags libsoup-2.4`

```
-pthread -I/usr/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -lsoup-2.4 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

I have vala 0.20.1. runing on elementaryos (the newest stable version). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue earlier today. It seems like the example is out of date. It's no longer called `soup_session_new`, the reference is now `soup_session_sync_new`. Use `new Soup.SessionSync ()` and it should work.

Here's a working example:

```
using Soup;

int main (string[] args) {

    string url = "http://google.com";

    stdout.printf ("Getting data from %s\n", url);

    var session = new Soup.SessionSync ();
    var message = new Soup.Message ("GET", url);

    session.send_message (message);
    stdout.write (message.response_body.data);
    return 0;
}
```